# Android - custom tab bar icon on ActionBarSherlock produces error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere in this project. The Main.xml is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_info_settings"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_customsettings"/>

</menu>
```

I have ic_menu_customsettings.png in drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_customsettings').
```

Am I supposed to do something more than put the png files in those folders to make them accessible by the ActionBar?

Comment: Your taking the right steps you dont need to do anything more, have you tried cleaning the project or restarting eclipse?

Comment: Yes. After cleaning the project, I get that error and 9 more errors all that say "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: Make sure there is no R files in your imports

Comment: The HoloEverywhere library has an R.java file, but it doesn't seem to be creating any conflicts.

Comment: After plenty of searching, I somehow found the answer right after posting this question. The correct line is: android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_customsettings"/>

Answer (score 0):

The correct line is:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_customsettings"/>
```